# Syntax error in C++ template member function

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and would like to get some help with fixing the following template function code without removing the function fl()

```
template<type T>
class Test
{
int f1(T* x);
};

template< T>
int Test::f1(T* x)
{
return 5:
};
```

Comment: Doh! You've forgotten to include the error message (c++ has more than one error message!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
template<typename T>
class Test
{
    int f1(T* x);
};

template<typename T>
int Test<T>::f1(T* x)
{
    return 5;
};
```

Note the keyword specifying the template argument `T` is either `typename` or `class`

Answer (score 3):

You have numerous syntax errors, but I guess your main issue is you need `Test<T>::f1` instead of `Test::f1`:

```
//typename, not type
template<typename T>
class Test
{
    int f1(T* x);
};

//      forgot typename
template<typename T>
int Test<T>::f1(T* x)
//need  ^^^
{
    return 5;
}
//^ no semicolon
```